# How to insert a pdf literal before and after a paragraph

Tags: luatex

How can I insert pdf literals before and after a paragraph node. My code does not work correctly. Thanks everybody for the help.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{luacode}
local pdf_node=node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
local pdf_node0=node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
pdf_node.data='/Span <</ActualText<FEFF041F04400438043204350442>>> BDC'
pdf_node0.data='EMC'
pdf_node.mode=2
pdf_node0.mode=2

local function insert_local_par(par,b)
par=node.insert_before(par,par,pdf_node)
par=node.insert_after(par,node.tail(par),pdf_node0)
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("insert_local_par",insert_local_par,"insert_local_par")
\end{luacode}
\begin{document}
Test

hello
\newpage
par

new par
\end{document}
```

Comment: A `local_par` node is not a node list, so you cannot use `insert_before` and `insert_after`.  Why don't you just use the `accsupp` package?  That would probably be much easier.

Comment: @Henri Menk In future i want to do package,which automatic do tagging of pdf. may be someone have idea,how insert before and after paragraf pdf literal,or it impossible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing it in a callback, you can examine the shipout box, searching for `local_par`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
local BDC = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
local EMC = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
BDC.data = '/Span <</ActualText<FEFF041F04400438043204350442>>> BDC'
BDC.mode = 2
EMC.data = 'EMC'
EMC.mode = 2

function tag_local_par(parent, level)
    local head = parent.list
    while head do
        -- texio.write_nl(string.rep("  ", level) .. tostring(head))
        if head.id == node.id"hlist" or head.id == node.id"vlist" then
            if head.list and head.list.id == node.id"local_par" then
                local par_list = head.list and head.list.next -- local_par should always be followed by a list
                head.list = node.insert_before(head.list, head.list, node.copy(BDC))
                par_list = node.insert_after(par_list, node.tail(par_list), node.copy(EMC))
            end
            tag_local_par(head, level + 1)
        end
        head = head.next
    end
end
```

```
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginShipout{\directlua{tag_local_par(tex.box["AtBeginShipoutBox"], 0)}}%
\begin{document}
Test

hello
\newpage
par

new par
\end{document}
```

Then, with `pdftotext` I get

```
Привет
Привет

1


Привет
Привет

2
```

---

A better tagging of paragraphs with their content can be done by processing the node list recursively like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495230.  Currently this takes place in the `post_linebreak_filter` callback, which is the correct callback to insert whatsits.  However, at this point hyphenation, kerning, and linebreaking have all taken place and we end up with all kinds of details of these processes in the node list.  That is why the output contains stray ligatures and hyphens, where there should be none.

The correct way to do this would be to convert scan the paragraphs in the `hyphenate` callback and them do some bookkeeping with node attributes or so and then later in the `post_linebreak_filter` collect all this information and place the `/ActualText`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
local converters = {}

local function convert(n)
    local id = n.id
    local type = node.type(id)

    local typeconv = converters[type]
    if typeconv then
        return typeconv(n) or ""
    else
        texio.write_nl("tag_par warning: no conversion available for " .. type)
        return ""
    end
end

function converters.hlist(n)
    local text = {}
    for n in node.traverse(n.list) do
        text[#text + 1] = convert(n)
    end
    return table.concat(text)
end

function converters.glyph(n)
    return utf.char(n.char)
end

function converters.glue(n)
    -- FIXME: any glue is treated like space
    return " "
end

function converters.kern(n)
    -- FIXME: any kern is just dropped
    return ""
end

function converters.disc(n)
    -- FIXME: does anybody care about discretionaries? Can we even distinguish
    --        user and hyphenation ones?
    local subtype = node.subtypes(n.id)[n.subtype]
    if subtype == "automatic" then
        return convert(n.replace)
    end
    return ""
end

local function tag_par(head, groupcode)
    local text = {}
    for n in node.traverse(head) do
        text[#text + 1] = convert(n)
    end

    local actual_text = table.concat(text)
    actual_text = string.gsub(actual_text, " +", " ") -- collapse consecutive spaces
    actual_text = string.gsub(actual_text, "^%s*(.-)%s*$", "%1") -- trim surrounding spaces

    local BDC = node.new("whatsit", "pdf_literal")
    BDC.data = "/Span <</ActualText(<p>" .. actual_text .. "</p>)>> BDC"
    BDC.mode = 2
    head = node.insert_before(head, head, BDC)

    local EMC = node.new("whatsit", "pdf_literal")
    EMC.data = "EMC"
    EMC.mode = 2
    head = node.insert_after(head, node.tail(head), EMC)

    return head
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter", tag_par, "tag_par")

\end{luacode}
\begin{document}
\input{lorem.tex}

\input{knuth.tex}
\newpage
\input{ward.tex}

\input{zapf.tex}
\end{document}
```

For illustration purposes I have marked the paragraphs with HTML-like `<p>...</p>` tags.  As can be seen from the output of `pdftotext`:

```
$ pdftotext test.pdf -
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur massa turpis, semper quis fringilla ut, viverra nec risus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec nunc lorem, sollicitudin vel sodales eget, vehicula nec mi. Proin ullamcorper rutrum nibh, at porttitor nunc euismod et. Donec faucibus nisi faucibus ipsum porttitor pharetra. Sed elementum, lectus nec congue imperdiet, ipsum leo viverra nisi, sit amet commodo odio odio id nisl. Fusce sagittis lobortis nisi sed consectetur. Nam egestas, sem ut fermentum convallis, ipsum tellus venenatis augue, eget condimentum risus quam id erat. Sed metus dui, sollicitudin pharetra pellen- tesque sed, placerat eget augue. Mauris sodales pretium tortor vitae rutrum. Proin quam sem, lobortis tincidunt pretium vitae, feugiat eu lacus.</p>

<p>Thus, I came to the conclusion that the designer of a new system must not only be the implementer and ï¬†rst large||scale user; the designer should also write the ï¬†rst user manual.</p>
<p>The separation of any of these four components would have hurt TEX signif- icantly. If I had not participated fully in all these activities, literally hundreds of improvements would never have been made, because I would never have thought of them or perceived why they were important.</p>

<p>But a system cannot be successful if it is too strongly inï¬‡uenced by a single person. Once the initial design is complete and fairly robust, the real test begins as people with many dierent viewpoints undertake their own experiments.</p>

1


<p>The Earth, as a habitat for animal life, is in old age and has a fatal illness. Several, in fact. It would be happening whether humans had ever evolved or not. But our presence is like the eect of an old|-|age patient who smokes many packs of cigarettes per day |=| and we humans are the cigarettes.</p>

<p>Coming back to the use of typefaces in electronic publishing: many of the new typographers receive their knowledge and information about the rules of typography from books, from computer magazines or the instruction manuals which they get with the purchase of a PC or software. There is not so much basic instruction, as of now, as there was in the old days, showing the dierences between good and bad typographic design. Many people are just fascinated by their PCâ•Žs tricks, and think that a widely||praised program, called up on the screen, will make everything automatic from now on.</p>

2
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch,but why we should use level variable?

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy The `level` variable is not needed in this case, but I usually define it anyway because it is useful for tracing.  I've added a commented line (`texio.write_nl...`) that prints the node tree as the list is traversed.  That is very useful to verify that the new nodes are inserted in the right positions.

Comment: But in Thank you very mutch,but your code have an issue,i mean if line contains alot of chars,it not works correct. So,in your example pdf literal inserted only in the first line of each paragraf,but it must inserted at the start and at the end of each paragraf.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Yes, you are right.  The problem is that I insert `EMC` at the end of the `hlist` which is only the first line.  I will fix this soon and update the answer.

Comment: Ok,i will wait. Thanks you very mutch for your help.

Comment: Also check please,will it works with two paragraphs with,for example,two lines. Or,if it difficult to fix it for you,may be exists another ways to insert pdf literals at the start and at the end of each paragraf.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy I have been thinking about this and the best solution is probably to use the `post_linebreak_filter`, because this always processes full paragraphs.  Then you can add a whatsit before and after the processed list.

Comment: Thankyou very mutch for your idea and it,in my opinion,the best variant,because in this case we not need use another package,but are you sure,that this callback give us paragraf,but not every line of document?

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy I had another look but I haven't found an elegant solution yet because the layout of the node list is something like `vlist (hlist (local_par glyph ... ) )`, i.e. the `local_par` is nested inside the `hlist` inside the `vlist` which contains the paragraph it describes.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy I have added an alternative solution based on my other answer for `mlist` conversion: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495230

Comment: Thank you very mutch for your example,but in my example pdf literal with russian actualtext inserted at the start and at the end of document,but not of each paragraf,because,as you will see,my document contains two paragrafs.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy I don't think I understand what you are saying. Do you want to have the Russian text instead of the contents of the paragraph?  If so, simply replace `<p>" .. actual_text .. "</p>` with the Russian text.  Also the example in your question has four paragraphs, so why are you talking about only two now?

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{luacode}
pdf.setcompresslevel(0)
local BDC = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
local EMC = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
BDC.data='/Span <</ActualText<FEFF041F04400438043204350442>>> BDC'
BDC.mode = 2
EMC.data = 'EMC'
EMC.mode = 2
function par(l,info)
l=node.insert_before(l,l,BDC)
l=node.insert_after(l,node.tail(l),EMC)
return l
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",par,"post_linebreak_filter")
\end{luacode}
\begin{document}
paragraf 1

paragraf 2
\end{document}

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy If you allocate the nodes only once, you have to use `node.copy`. I'm surprised that LuaTeX did not crash even though you referenced a non-existent node. Full example: https://termbin.com/18yo

Comment: Thank you very mutch. Now it seems,that it works very good,but why it insert only one literal,if i not use nod.copy function?

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy After inserting the node into a list it will be freed as soon as it is written to the PDF.  In many cases LuaTeX crashes when you try to use a node that has already been written.