# How to annotate mathematical material with /ActualText?

Tags: luatex

Please help me to create a regular expression that for example replaces `$a+b$` with `\(a+b\)` and `$$a-b$$` with `\[a-b\]`, so that I can then hook into the `\(...\)` and `\[...\]` macros to annotate the contained material with `/ActualText` for accessibility. The replacement has to be done if there is no `\` char before each `$`.

Here is my code doing that. For `$$` it works very well, but for `$` I have errors, because in some places `$` is replaced with `\(` or, maybe, `\)` even if there is the `\` char before.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\directlua{require("test.lua")}
test
summ
\$$$a=\sum_{i=0}^n{a_i^2}+1\$$$ \$$a-b=0$\$
\[a=\sum_{i=0}^n{a_i^2}-1\] \(a=\sum_{i=0}^n{a_i^2}\)
\end{document}
```

`test.lua`

```lua
function process_input_buffer(buffer)
texio.write_nl("callback get line "..buffer)
buffer=buffer:gsub("([^\\]?)%$%$(.-)([^\\]?)%$%$","%1\\[%2%3\\]")
texio.write_nl("callback get line "..buffer)
buffer=buffer:gsub("([^\\]?)%$(.-)([^\\]?)%$","%1\\(%2%3\\)")
texio.write_nl("callback get line "..buffer)
return buffer
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer",process_input_buffer,"buffer")
```

Comment: you ask for a regular expression but you seem to be using Lua patterns which are a lot less expressive than regular expressions.

Comment: @David Carlisle Yes,may be you right. In python,for example for $ i can do "r"(?<!\\)\$(.+?)(?<!\\)\$"",but why with $$ all works and with $ it not works in lua?

Comment: Lua Patterns have some slight similarities with regular expressions but they are a completely different system. Also why do this in a callback, changing `$` to `\(` in a callback just makes things slow, Lua has to change `$`  to  `\(` then tex replaces `\(` by `$` to start math mode.  the benefits of using `\(` rather than `$` are all about having matching delimiters _in the file_ to help editor highlighting etc,

Comment: @David Carlisle I replace $$ and $ in callback,because i cant override $$ or $,but i can override \[ and \] command,so the best solution is use callback,which replace $ by \(\) and $$ by \[\],but i dont understode,how fix issue in my code with $,because as you se in log with $$ all ok.

Comment: And why don't you just change the input then? There are enough tools around which can change a file based on regular expressions...

Comment: @Skillmon because in future i want to implement this in package and lua almost solve my problem,but i not understoode why it replace $ on \( in situation,if before $ is \ char.

Comment: My version, ignore `\$` (in perl), replace `$...$` to `\(...\) `.....`~ s/(?<!\\)\${2}(.+?)(?<!\\)\${2}/\\\[$1\\\]/gms;` .... replace ` $$...$$` to `\[...\]`....`~ s/(?<!\\)\${1}(.+?)(?<!\\)\${1}/\\\($1\\\)/gms;`

Comment: That is a pretty tough one because you can have nested `$`, e.g. `$a + b * \text{d $e$ f} + g$`.

Comment: Ok,help me please find very good library for regex. I found,in my opinion,very good library https://github.com/NexusInstruments/RegExpUtils/,but this library have an issue "
lua:3: attempt to index a nil value (global 'Apollo". So,help me please found module Apollo. Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: Perhaps you should consult directly at (https://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/luatex).

Comment: As Henri just observed nested `$` expressions make this also impossible to do with regex (you can not match brackets in true regular expressions, you need an extended system that can count)  but note I did not say that you could not do this with Lua patterns I just observed that your question was (and still is) inconsistent as it asks in the text for help with a regular expression but it shows an example of Lua patterns. Nie Lua can count so if you really needed this you could march on each $ separately and then decide the action in a Lua function

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Counting will not help you either.  Consider `$\text{$a$} b \text{$c$}$` vs `$\text{$a \text{$b$} c$}$`.

Comment: @HenriMenke yes I know:-) I was using "counting" to mean "use a turing complete language to handle the tokens you get from the regex match" :-) but anyway I see you have given a more complete answer on the luatex list already.

Comment: I partially solved my problem with $. The problem was in lazy quantificator. Now i did ([^\\]?)%$(.-)([^\\])%$ and it seems,that it works. May be exists ways to redefine $$ and $ in lualatex,because i want,that for formulas with $$ and $ inserted actualtext,so i decided use lua callbacks,to replace it in \[\] or \(\),because in this redefined commands i do insertion of actualtext in formula. May be you know another ways,how insert actualtext in formulas with $$ or $ (actualtext must contains tex notation of formula)? Thanks very mutch everybody for the help.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy I saw on your profile that a lot of your questions have answers but you haven't accepted any of them.  Please revisit these answers and either accept them or ask for further clarification.

Comment: @Henri Menke \documentclass{article}
\def\actualtext#1{%
        \pdfextension literal direct {/Span <</ActualText(#1)>> BDC}%
        #1%
        \pdfextension literal direct {EMC}%
    }
    \def\grabinline#1${\actualtext{#1}$}
    \def\grabdisplay#1$${\actualtext{#1}$$}
    
    \everymath{\grabinline}
    \everydisplay{\grabdisplay}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    $ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 $
    
    $$ a^4 + b^4 = c^4
$$
\end{document}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than trying to process the document source and having to fight with all kinds of problems like catcodes, it would be much easier to tag formulas with `/ActualText` in the `mlist_to_hlist` callback.

In a private email Ulrike told me that you want to tag math for accessibility purposes.  Below I present my humble solution.

## Features

1. Inside the callback the `mlist` is walked linearly (not recursively) and the `convert` function is called for every node in the list.
2. The `convert` function inspects the node's type and looks up the appropriate conversion function in the table `converters`.  If no converter is available, a warning is printed in the log and an empty string is returned, i.e. the node is ignored.
3. The conversion functions typically just call `convert` on each of their fields and concatenate the result in a sensible manner.  Conversion only stops, when an ignored node is encountered or the node has type `math_char`, because there we know what to do.
4. For nodes of type `math_char` we extract the character.  The character is stored as the number of the slot in the font.  That is why we require `unicode-math`, otherwise the result is too ambiguous because it depends on the font.  For Unicode characters we can either emit the Unicode character directly or we can use the table of Unicode math symbols to look up the command to produce that symbol and emit this.

## Limitations

1. The code below is only an example.  Many node types are not handled, especially the `sub_box` type, so embedded horizontal and vertical mode material is simply lost.
2. Nested `mlist`s currently fail badly.  I think this is a limitation of `/ActualText`, not being able to be nested.
3. Fences are just output as characters with `\left` and `\right`.  Manually scaled delimiters are fences nested in `sub_box` nodes, which are not handled currently.
4. In the source file we use one math operator `\Res`.  This currently outputs as `Res`, i.e. the markup is entirely lost.  This is actually a very tricky one, because what `\Res` essentially does is `\mathop{<switch to text font but stay in math mode> Res}`.  The operation of switching to the text font is in principle encoded in the `math_char` nodes' `fam` field, but not handled right now.
5. More limitations are marked in the code with `FIXME`.

You can also find this code with some other random improvements on my GitHub:
https://gist.github.com/hmenke/a41574ef0b5000635986f0dec73e066f

**`tag_math.lua`**

```lua
local unimath_symbols = {}
local f = io.open(kpse.find_file("unicode-math-table.tex"), "r")
for line in f:lines() do
    local slot, cmd = string.match(line, [[^\UnicodeMathSymbol{"([%a%d]*)}{([^}%s]*)%s*}]])
    if slot then
        unimath_symbols[tonumber(slot, 16)] = cmd
    end
end
f:close()

local function convert_char(c)
    return unimath_symbols[c] or utf.char(c)
end

local converters = {}

local function convert(n)
    local id = n.id
    local type = node.type(id)

    local typeconv = converters[type]
    if typeconv then
        return typeconv(n) or ""
    else
        texio.write_nl("tag_math warning: no conversion available for " .. type)
        return ""
    end
end

function converters.noad(n)
    if not (n.nucleus.head or n.nucleus.char) then
        -- This is a thing, e.g. ${}$ is just an empty noad
        return ""
    end
    local result = convert(n.nucleus)

    local subtype = node.subtypes(n.id)[n.subtype]
    if subtype == "oplimits" or subtype == "opdisplaylimits" then
        result = result .. "\\limits"
    end

    if n.sub then
        result = result .. "_{" .. convert(n.sub) .. "}"
    end
    if n.sup then
        result = result .. "^{" .. convert(n.sup) .. "}"
    end

    return result
end

function converters.math_char(n)
    return convert_char(n.char)
end

function converters.sub_mlist(n)
    local result = ""
    for n in node.traverse(n.head) do
        result = result .. convert(n)
    end
    return result
end

function converters.fence(n, subtype)
    local subtype = node.subtypes(n.id)[n.subtype]
    local leftright = { left = "\\left", right = "\\right" }

    local result
    if n.delim.small_char ~= 0 then
        result = convert_char(n.delim.small_char)
    elseif n.delim.large_char ~= 0 then
        result = convert_char(n.delim.large_char)
    else
        result = "."
    end

    return leftright[subtype] .. result
end

function converters.fraction(n)
    local num = convert(n.num)
    local denom = convert(n.denom)
    return "\\frac{" .. num .. "}{" .. denom .. "}"
end

function converters.radical(n)
    local result = "\\sqrt{" .. convert(n.nucleus) .. "}"

    if n.sub then
        result = result .. "_{" .. convert(n.sub) .. "}"
    end
    if n.sup then
        result = result .. "^{" .. convert(n.sup) .. "}"
    end

    return result
end

function converters.style(n)
    return "\\" .. n.style .. "style"
end

function converters.accent(n)
    local result = convert(n.nucleus)
    if n.accent then
        result = convert(n.accent) .. "{" .. result .. "}"
    end
    if n.bot_accent then
        result = convert(n.bot_accent) .. "{" .. result .. "}"
    end
    if n.sub then
        result = result .. "_{" .. convert(n.sub) .. "}"
    end
    if n.sup then
        result = result .. "^{" .. convert(n.sup) .. "}"
    end
    return result
end

function converters.glue(n)
    -- FIXME: any glue is treated like space
    return " "
end

function converters.kern(n)
    -- FIXME: any kern is just dropped
    return ""
end

local function tag_math(head, display_type, need_penalties)
    local text = {}
    for n in node.traverse(head) do
        text[#text + 1] = convert(n)
    end

    -- concatenate, escape, and remove quotes
    local actual_text = string.sub(string.format("%q", table.concat(text, "")), 2, -2)
    if display_type == "display" then
        actual_text = "\\\\[" .. actual_text .. "\\\\]"
    elseif display_type == "text" then
        actual_text = "\\\\(" .. actual_text .. "\\\\)"
    end

    local BDC = node.new("whatsit", "pdf_literal")
    BDC.data = "/Span <</ActualText(" .. actual_text .. ")>> BDC"
    BDC.mode = 2
    head = node.insert_before(head, head, BDC)

    local EMC = node.new("whatsit", "pdf_literal")
    EMC.data = "EMC"
    EMC.mode = 2
    head = node.insert_after(head, node.tail(head), EMC)

    return node.mlist_to_hlist(head, display_type, need_penalties)
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("mlist_to_hlist", tag_math, "tag_math")
```

**`test.tex`**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\DeclareMathOperator\Res{Res}
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{dofile("tag_math.lua")}}
\begin{document}

$
    \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_\gamma f\left(x^{\symbf{N}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times 10}}\right)
    = \sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k)\Res(f;a_k)\,.
$

\[
    \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_\gamma f\left(x^{\symbf{N}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times 10}}\right)
    = \sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k)\Res(f;a_k)\,.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: original output]

Running `pdftotext` on the output I get

```
$ pdftotext test.pdf -
\(\frac{1}{2\mitpi\miti}\int\limits_{\mitgamma}\mitf\left\lparen\mitx^{\mbfN\in\BbbC^{\mitN\times10}}\right\rparen\equal\sum\limits_{\mitk\equal1}^{\mitm}\mitn\lparen\mitgamma\mathsemicolon\mita_{\mitk}\rparenRes\lparen\mitf\mathsemicolon\mita_{\mitk}\rparen \mathperiod\)
\[\frac{1}{2\mitpi\miti}\int\limits_{\mitgamma}\mitf\left\lparen\mitx^{\mbfN\in\BbbC^{\mitN\times10}}\right\rparen\equal\sum\limits_{\mitk\equal1}^{\mitm}\mitn\lparen\mitgamma\mathsemicolon\mita_{\mitk}\rparenRes\lparen\mitf\mathsemicolon\mita_{\mitk}\rparen \mathperiod\]
```

This is *almost* valid TeX code and it *almost* round-trips.

In this example one has to fix `\rparenRes` to `\rparen\opertorname{Res}`, but then it gives almost identical output (apart from `\int` which is missing `\limits`).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\(\frac{1}{2\mitpi\miti}\int\limits_{\mitgamma}\mitf\left\lparen\mitx^{\mbfN\in\BbbC^{\mitN\times10}}\right\rparen\equal\sum\limits_{\mitk\equal1}^{\mitm}\mitn\lparen\mitgamma\mathsemicolon\mita_{\mitk}\rparen\operatorname{Res}\lparen\mitf\mathsemicolon\mita_{\mitk}\rparen \mathperiod\)
\[\frac{1}{2\mitpi\miti}\int\limits_{\mitgamma}\mitf\left\lparen\mitx^{\mbfN\in\BbbC^{\mitN\times10}}\right\rparen\equal\sum\limits_{\mitk\equal1}^{\mitm}\mitn\lparen\mitgamma\mathsemicolon\mita_{\mitk}\rparen\operatorname{Res}\lparen\mitf\mathsemicolon\mita_{\mitk}\rparen \mathperiod\]
\end{document}
```

[image: round-tripped output]

Comment: Imho the OP wants to get the tex code of the math inside the /Actualtext.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But then it's just a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452532/plain-luatex-detecting-if-displaymath-is-ended-by-or-ustopdisplaymath

Comment: @henri-menke,@Ulrike Fischer Yes,i want to se latex notation of formula,or another notation,but it must be show text of formula in actualtext. Also i not understoode,how i can disable callback in equation and enable it again.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy You have to make a choice.  It is **either** catcode stability and no balancing issues using the callback **or** no verbatim material and fragile `$` counting using something like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452532/plain-luatex-detecting-if-displaymath-is-ended-by-or-ustopdisplaymath.  You can't have both.

Comment: @Henri Menke but how get text of formula from node,which give this callback.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy You can't get the TeX code of the formula using the callback.  For that you have to use a fragile macro solution.  Alternatively you could design your own macros for math typesetting which do the appropriate thing which is much better than trying to hook into low-level TeX syntax.

Comment: @Henri Menke I try use your solution,which you propose in luatex mailing list. It works,if i not use numeration of pages,but when i do it,i have an empty document. Help me please solve my problem,because i haven't any idea,how to fix this issue. Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy If I add `\pagestyle{empty}` to the code in this answer, it works fine.  `pdftotext` still outputs whatever I put in `/ActualText`.

Comment: @Henri Menke Ok,but when i replace in my code \thispagestyle{empty} on \pagestyle{empty} it still not works. I also sent privately to you in attachment my document,which not works. I can't understand,why \pagestyle{empty} do my document empty. Please,if it not dificult to you,send me please document,which show even with using \pagestyle{empty}. If you want,you can send me an example privately on my email. Thanks very mutch for your help.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy I have updated the answer with something more complete.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Your solution is great .... useful enough for those of us who use `moodle` and don't have access to the configuration (by default the mathematical mode uses `\(...\)`), can you extend your answer to accept `\text{...}`?

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL No, that requires macro support and extensive refactoring of the code presented here.  However, you can add your own `converters.sub_box` to handle embedded non-math node lists.

Comment: @HenriMenke: I understand, however your code has saved me a lot of work (I'm a `moodle` user), and it's more like the script I own. Greetings